# version 70 about the TrackballControls.js rotation

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

My question in github--
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6043#issuecomment-73478885
I know TrackballControls.js  be used for controlling a camera, not a model.
But I want rotation model with this TrackballControls.js.When I control the model with mouse,I can pan,zoom,rotate.When I rotate the model, I won't feel in a rotating camera, but seemed to rotate the model itself.  I need a mouse event.

method:

```
controls.target = model.position; 
or controls.target.copy( model.position )
```

they no use;

Comment: Maybe http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html will help.

Comment: thanks for your answer,but The effect I want as like http://www.lao3d.com/model.html?modelid=14743,you can see it,operate the model,translate,rotation ,scale; rotation after Translation,you can find,it is different of the TrackballControls.js.Thank you once again

Comment: I see. You will have to write your own ObjectController to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the lao3d.com Viewer you want to rotate the object around the worlds Y and X  axis independent of its translation.

So I made this little example http://jsfiddle.net/nk3977jb/1/ .

It takes into consideration that the camera might be rotated.
And therefore creates its current Up and Right vector using the quaternion of the camera to get the up and view vector to then calculate the cross product of it.

```
    var view = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    view.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
    var cross = new THREE.Vector3();
    cross.crossVectors(view, camera.up);
```

You can think of view being -Z going into the Screen, +Y being the cameras up vector pointing upwards from whichever rotation the camera has and cross being the crossproduct of -Z and +Y therefore pointing right.

With these axis setup you can rotate the object around them.